# C# bool arrays, COM interop, and access violations

Tags: .net, boolean, marshalling, com-interop

I have a COM component written in C++. One of the MIDL interfaces has a function defined like:

```
HRESULT __stdcall GetValues(
    int length,
    [ref, size_is(*length)] VARIANT_BOOL out[]);
```

`GetValues` just populates the `out` array with values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    out[i] = (i % 2) != 0;
```

I've tried to call it from C# using the following:

```
private bool[] mValues = new bool[100];
...
myComObject.GetValues(100, ref this.mValues[0]);
```

I'm getting access violation errors. I think the C++ is interpreting the `bool`s as 2-byte values, whereas in C# they're only allocated as 1-byte values.

I've looked at [Default Marshaling for Boolean Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f.aspx) but I'm not sure how to apply that to my situation. The `MarshalAs` attribute doesn't seem to change anything. I'm not sure how to use it for passing an array by reference?

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U1)]
private bool[] mValues = new bool[100];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VARIANT_BOOL` is indeed a 2-byte value: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/22/329884.aspx

So when you marshal it as `UnmanagedType.VariantBool`, you're not changing anything because you're marshalling it in as exactly the same thing that's being returned anyway.

What I would try first is `UnmanagedType.U1`. If that doesn't work, I would try to a `short[]` instead of `bool[]`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions Joel. I tried `UnmanagedType.U1` with no success. Unless someone suggests a better alternative, I will settle with using `short[]`.

Comment: By the way, could you add to your question a bit of code demonstrating where you put `[MarshalAs(...)]`?

Comment: @emddudley: I see. I think placing it on a field would only affect how it is marshalled if the field was exposed through COM. I was thinking it might be possible to apply it in the call to `GetValues()`, but apparently attributes can't be applied that way. Unless the component is changed, I think you're stuck using a data type of the same size (or at least same total size, such as `bool[200]` for `GetValues(100,...)`).